# Выпадающий список в excel на python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Есть в Excel выпадающий список с нечетким поиском. И есть dataframe который после манипуляций выгружаю в excel документ, он каждый раз новый. Отправляю этот документ другим людям для заполнения. В этом получившемся документе хотелось бы сделать заполнение значений в столбце, только значениями из справочника(выпадающего списка). Можно это сделать как-то на питоне? Если просто взять ячейку с выпадающим списо, я могу ее копировать в любую другую ячейку и протянуть до конца, то есть на VBA похоже я смогу это сделать. Можно ли это сделать по средства python?

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/validation.html

Comment: @MaxU подскажите, какая из библиотек наиболее функциональна для эксель, есть еще xlwings и подобные

Comment: по-моему, это зависит от задачи - не думаю что есть "серебрянная пуля". Если бы была такая универсальная библиотека - остальные бы вымерли...

Answer (score 0):

## Limiting input to a value in a dropdown list.

Выбор значения из выпадающего списка

```
txt = 'Select a value from a drop down 
list (using a cell range)'
worksheet.write('A15', txt)
worksheet.data_validation(
         'B15', 
         {'validate': 'list', 
          'source': '=$E$4:$G$4'}
)
```

Найдено тут: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_data_validate.html